# Using a variable on a PostgreSQL function to drop a schema

Tags: postgresql, function, schema, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a function on PostgreSQL, and I have some problem to use a local variable. Here's my code :

```
DECLARE query RECORD;
DECLARE schema_name TEXT;
BEGIN
        FOR query IN SELECT * FROM context WHERE created_at + make_interval(days => duration) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP LOOP
            SELECT lower(quote_ident(query.title)) INTO schema_name;
            DROP SCHEMA schema_name CASCADE;
            DELETE FROM context WHERE id = query.id;  
        END LOOP;
RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The **select** and **delete** queries work fine, and I've made a test returning the value of **schema_name** variable, and it's OK.

My problem is with this line :

`DROP SCHEMA schema_name CASCADE;`

I get an error as "the schema 'schema_name' doesn't exist". 
I'd really appreciate any ideas for how to use this variable to do the drop query.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you only need one `DECLARE` block for all variables. Not one block for each variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for this:

```
DECLARE 
  query RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR query IN SELECT id, lower(title) as title 
               FROM context 
               WHERE created_at + make_interval(days => duration) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
  LOOP
    execute format('DROP SCHEMA %I CASCADE', query.title);
    DELETE FROM context WHERE id = query.id;  
   END LOOP;
RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

I also removed the unnecessary SELECT statement to make the title lower case, this is better done in the query directly.

Also: variable assignment is faster with `:=` then with `select`, so:

```
schema_name := lower(quote_ident(query.title));
```

would be better if the variable was needed.